# Dark mode switch CSS not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Here,](https://mtm828.github.io/) I have a dark theme switch in the top navbar, it's actually just a checkbox but with CSS which turns it into a switch. It's W3Schools's code but with minor edits by me, but now the CSS for the switch (checkbox) is gone, what am I doing wrong?

**Note:** It used to work fine before, but it broke after I updated [CSS.css](https://mtm828.github.io/RECOURCES/CSS.css) or [JS.js](https://mtm828.github.io/RECOURCES/JS.js), I don't remember.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you! :)

Comment: Which link are we supposed to click on?

Comment: please create snippet and give us

Comment: Learn [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Everything we need to answer your question should be in the question itself, so the question and answers are still useful to people who land here in the future when the websites you've linked to are long gone.

Comment: @Rojo the "Here" link leads to the site, CSS.css leads to my site's CSS and JS.js leads to my site's JS. And I did see them, have I forgotten something? :(

Comment: @Domino But I have like 215 lines of CSS code! :P

Comment: Did you even read the articles? Read the articles completely, maybe 5 or 6 times. Then, come back here and remove whatever code is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rojo ._. Please calm down, you sound pretty aggressive.

Comment: @MTM828 Bear in mind 90% of the people posting new questions on this site don't even bother reading the rules and FAQ, so it's hard to be patient.

Comment: @Domino Well yeah I did read it... but not really well LOL. But I still do read them at least, I have the informed badge to prove it. :P

Comment: @Domino Do you think I should delete the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `onclick` event to the checkbox.

Change this...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="darkModeSwitch" class="">
<span class="slider" onclick="toggleDarkMode()"></span>
```

To this...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="darkModeSwitch" class="" onclick="toggleDarkMode()">
<span class="slider"></span>
```

p.s. if you are using something to convert the checkbox into a "switch" you might also want to check why that is not working.

Comment: "p.s. if you are using something to convert the checkbox into a "switch" you might also want to check why that is not working." That was actually the real point, know why it isn't working?

Comment: @MTM828 Yes, it looks like you are missing a closing bracket } in your css after this: `.sticky + .pageContent {
    padding-top: 100px;`